# Surjection from a scheme of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme, $X$ a scheme locally of finite type over $S$, $Y$ a scheme over $S$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a surjective morphism of $S$-schemes. Under what conditions is $Y$ locally of finite type over $S$?

Comment: What do you mean for "surjective morphism"?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos morphism surjective on the underlying topological spaces.

Comment: Surjectivity on the level of topological spaces is very far from strong enough to say anything about whether $Y$ is locally of finite type or not. Consider the two schemes $\operatorname{Spec} k$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,x_2,\cdots]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,\cdots)$, with map given by $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the ring map $x_i\mapsto 0$. Then this is surjective (in fact, a homeomorphism) on topological spaces, but $Y$ is nowhere close to locally of finite type.